# Should classes with same names in the same packages in different deployment units conflict in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm seeing an interesting behavior in some of the code I inherited where there's a project with a dependency jar in which there exists a class with the same name and in the same package as a class in the project:

Eclipse project:

**src/com.abc.d.E**

depends on **XYZ.jar** in which there exists a **com.abc.d.E.class**

Just curious if this setup is legal in Java.  According to Eclipse, which doesn't mark it as an error and allows to create a new class that shadows an existing class in a dependency jar, except when one tries to rename such an existing class in the workspace - then it produces the following warning:

> "Binary references to a refactored element have been found.  They will
>   not be updated, which may lead to problems if you proceed."

And then this forward refactoring is allowed.  However, if one would like to refactor backwards to a conflicting name, the following message appears in Eclipse:

> "Type named 'E' already exists in package 'com.abc.d'

So is it

- a correct Java
- an allowed inconsistency in Eclipse's behavior or
- .an Eclipse bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both classes where accessible to the same classloader (for example if both jar files find themselves on the same classpath), then only one of them would be loaded (probably the one that's first in the list), which would lead to all kinds of nasty results, esepcially if they don't behave the same.

Assume library 1 uses `E.frobnicate()` while library 2 expects there to be a `E.frob()` method: one of those will get a `NoSuchMethodError` and generally just fail spectacularly.

Generally speaking, the package name and class name should *uniquely* identify a class. And if that's no longer the case then you'll get into trouble.

You *can* work around the issue as long as you never need those two libraries to be accessible from the same classloader, then the JVM can handle it just fine (because FQCN *plus* the classloader is used internally by the JVM to uniquely identify a class during runtime).

The only case where this is *intentionally* done is if some library re-implements classes of another one in a binary-compatible manner. See [log4j-over-slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) for an example.

Comment: The Eclipse workspace in this case gets packaged into a jar which gets put onto the same classpath with the dependency jar which (classpath) gets formulated by a loop in a bash script and so the  dependency jar ends up behind the workspace jar.  So apparently the version in the first jar gets used (as there's no exception on startup of JVM).  Or are they in fact get loaded by different classloaders (as names are the same and there's no runtime exception)?

Comment: Simeon: if they're both simply put on the classpath, then they are both loaded by the same classloader and thus only one of the classes will actually be used. If you get no exception, then you're lucky and the class is not actually used from the other jar or it's "compatible enough".

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that states you cannot have two classes with the same package/class name.

This happens all the time when you accidentally have two versions of a library on your classpath, leading to things like `IncompatibleClassChangeError` or getting the wrong version because you're at the mercy of class load order.

Eclipse, OTOH, has to *do* something with those classes other than just loading the first one encountered on the classpath. You can't rename to something that already exists, because that wouldn't make any sense.

Renaming something out from under something that *already* exists is *likely* an error, but can't be *guaranteed* to be an error, because you might be *fixing* a naming problem, rather than just creating a new/different one.

Comment: Eclipse complains about binary references when I'm attempting to rename the class names in the project to be different from the ones in the dependency jar.  Why in your opinion this refactoring doesn't make any sense?  I see it as explicitly preventing the potential troubles which Eclipse should've prevented for someone who created this situation in the first place.

Comment: Instead Eclipse only refuses to rename it back into the conflicting (shadow) situation it had allowed in the first place.  In other words, first rename gave a warning and was permitted but the second gave an error and a reject, which should have happened in the very beginning when the first attempt to create the conflicting class was attempted.

Comment: @SimeonLeyzerzon It *warns*, it just doesn't update the references *inside existing binaries*: that's renaming out-from-under something that may already be referencing it (and in this case, defining it as well). That's likely a problem, but not *intrinsically* a problem, and allows you to fix a naming conflict you've introduced in *your* code. Renaming *to* something already defined in a binary is *certainly* an error, except in the pathological case where you really believe your class will be loaded first--but it's very dangerous, so disallowed.